# Excel String Evaluation reference on named range fails

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a named range called 'income' and a EVAL function

```
Function EVAL(Ref As String)
Application.Volatile
EVAL = Evaluate(Ref)
End Function
```

Next is a String "income * 1.19".
I use the EVAL function to calculate the value. But this works only for the first value in the named range.

Here a short example: [File](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10095862/example.xlsm)

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to enter your formula to excel cells as an array formula. Follow the steps:

1. enter formula to cells
2. select range with formulas
3. press F2
4. press Ctrl + Shift + Enter

Comment: Thanks a lot. That did the trick. But now I realized that I've got trouble with the EVAL function. =EVAL("income*1.19") works, but =EVAL("AND(income>40, income<80)") shows always false. Any idea?

Comment: you're right, but I have no idea why. you don't need your formula to do that? it seems that you need to do it in different way.

Comment: Actually most of my checks have multiple conditions, I just wanted to start with the easieast... And I thought, that EVAL would work...

Comment: AND returns *one* result based on whether *all* rows of the range meet the conditions, not an array of results for each row. It's nothing to do with `Evaluate`. You need an IF function, or a multiplication of conditions.

Comment: Ahhh I see, Excel takes all values of the array!!! So I need one way that it takes only the values of that specific row. Thanks for the hint! But if I'm doing only income<40 it caluclates only on the specific row...

Comment: Yep - your formula needs to be something like `(income>10)*(income<60)`

Comment: Thanks! And what would I have to do for something like OR(income>10, income<60)?

Comment: That wouldn't make a lot of sense! ;) Typically for an OR condition in an array you add rather than multiplying.